# Ideas Why Column Group Page Break Not Working?

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2012

I am building a schedule, and would like the report to have a page break in between semesters. The dataset itself has 4 quarters; my terms parameter decides which quarter goes to which semester with this query:

```
select distinct t.name AS 'termName', CASE WHEN t.name IN ('Q1', 'Q2') THEN 'S1' 
    WHEN t.name IN ('Q3', 'Q4') THEN 'S2' ELSE NULL END AS 'termLabel'
```

The term name pulling in the report is coming from my main query:

```
select distinct ps.name AS 'periodScheduleName', pd.name AS 'periodName', CASE WHEN tm.name IN ('Q1', 'Q2') THEN 'S1'
    WHEN tm.name IN ('Q3', 'Q4') THEN 'S2' ELSE NULL END AS 'termName', 
    ISNULL(x.staffNumber, '') AS 'staffNumber', COALESCE(x.employeeName, 'No Staff Assigned') AS 'employeeName', 
    ISNULL(x.departmentName, '') AS 'departmentName',
    c.name AS 'courseName', CAST(c.number as varchar(25)) AS 'courseNumber',  CAST(s.number as varchar(25)) AS 'sectionNumber',
    ca.name AS 'calendarName'
```

I have a column group on termName, with periods displaying beneath it. Within my column group I have "Page break options: Between each instance of a group" marked.

The data displays fine, but it's not splitting Semester 1 and Semester 2 over different pages. What am I missing here? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Page break in column groups are a real pain, in fact I've never actually got it work as expected.

The best options would probably be to move the semester to the row group and put the page break there. If all you want to do is split them onto different pages then that should do the trick.

If this does not work for some reason, share some sample data as text (better still as a script to generate the table of data) and a sketch of what you expect the final output to look like, and I'll try to put something togther.